# Is there any common X11 program?

Tags: x11

You can think of `echo` or `cat` as common terminal program. You can call blindly:

```
echo "hello world"
```

in bash for example and it will work. You will see the output.

I am looking for something like this for X11, something you can type (again blindly) and assuming user is working in X11 she/he will see visual output (so I am not asking how to detect X11, it works, this is assumption).

It could be even X11 command (like creating bare window with close button) if it is possible to call X11 subsystem from bash. Please note, I am not talking about problem like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/how-to-show-a-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux because tools like "zenity" (no question, it is useful) is not installed by default.

Important note: I need something persistent, something which will stay until power is off or user explicitly closes it.

Comment: xeyes, xterm, xclock, ...

Comment: @JeffSchaller, why so shy :-), you gave perfect answer. Please post it as such, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: This depends on the target distro, and what they install by default. I have X installed but none of xterm, xeyes, or xclock. Installing X doesn't necessarily install any of these.

Comment: @muru, that's bad (for me). Did you remove any of those? I am thinking especially about xterm.

Comment: Nope. I use Arch Linux, so I install what I need. xterm was never on the system (and likely never will be). Similarly for systems built from a minimal Debian or Ubuntu - if you do `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, sure, xterm might come along, but not if you install only the things you want.

Comment: Likewise for Fedora, the default setup doesn't include `xterm`, `xeyes` or `xclock`.

Comment: `xlogo` perhaps?

Comment: The "x11-apps" Debian package includes a few things; must not be in the minimal Arch install: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/x11-apps

Comment: my interpretation of https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=xorg-&maintainer=&flagged= is that you install each program that you want. I don't know Arch well enough to know what a minimal install includes.

Comment: @JeffSchaller a minimal install? https://www.archlinux.org/groups/amd64/base/ Certainly not X11. And even if you do something like `pacman -S gnome-shell` to install X + GNOME stuff, xterm won't be in the picture.

Comment: oohh, woops, I mistakenly read muru's comment as the OP's. Knowing the distribution, or more importantly, the choices made during installation, would be key here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There really isn't any such command. Nor can there (within reason) be. The user could be, for example, using a full-screen app, and his/her compositing window manager refuses to put anything on top of it (as it'd disrupt the full-screen experience).

And of course blindly typing doesn't work—a terminal might not be focused. You could wind up typing your totally awesome command into a Stack Exchange answer instead of a terminal, where of course it won't be run.

If you want a command you can run that will *probably* display something, the basic ones that come with Xorg are a good guess: `xlogo`, `xev`, `xfd`, `xmessage`, `xeyes`, among several others. Of those, `xmessage` is sort of like zenity, but much more primitive (but probably more likely to be installed) and `xeyes`—will certainly get the user's attention. Remember in a shell script you can detect "not installed" (exit code 127) and try another on the list.

If you want to convey *useful* information to the user, and the user is using a modern desktop environment, your best bet is to send a desktop notification with `notify-send` (part of libnotify). That should persist until the user closes it.

Comment: Thank you for useful answer, just for the record by blindly execution I meant I can execute command without prior checking if the given program is installed (or installing it). Also the part about fullscreen etc. is irrelevant for me, because I know I have a terminal, my script is running and so on, the only question is what is the program (for XWindow) that is present on the system. One again thank you for the answer and a good selection list.

Comment: @greenoldman as you know you have a terminal, you might be able to back that command out and open another terminal.